# Move all mp4 from folders into another folder

Tags: files, copy, mp4

Currently I have a folder  with alot of mp4 files located like this:

```
Folder1/titleplaylist/mp4files
Folder1/titleplaylist2/mp4files
Folder1/titleplaylist3/mp4files
```

Currently I'm using this command:

```sh
sudo find -type f -iname "*.mp4" -exec cp -av {} /home/user123/set/Folder1/ \;
```

But it only moves mp4 files from (Folder1). I want it also to move or copy the mp4 files from folder (mp4files).

Keep in mind that the folder names are just examples. Is there a way to do this without specifying the folder names? Like in my above command but that it also includes the files from all subdirectories and moves/copies them?

Comment: First of all, if these subdirectories are within your user's home directory, or any other directory owned by your regular user, then you don't need `sudo` for it. Any file that got moved with `sudo`, will end up in the ownership of root, and you would need an extra effort to give them back to your regular user.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, `mp4files` is a directory? So an actual sample media file would look like `Folder1/titleplaylist/mp4files/sample.mp4` ?

Comment: Take care when using `find -exec cp`. This will overwrite files with duplicate filenames in different directories. Then, you should use the form `-exec cp -t TARGET {} +` instead of `-exec cp {} TARGET \;`. However, I don't see why your problem occurs, It should also copy files from all subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested a command like

```
find -type f -iname "*.mp4" -exec cp -av {} /home/user123/set/Folder1/ \;
```

and it works.
You were missing the backslash, although without it the command doesn't work for me...